# How to extract address in excel?

Tags: excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have addresses in one cell and I want to extract them in different cells on the same row. Some cells have four lines of address and some have three. I am able to easily split using text to column and various delimiters for the ones with three but not the ones with four.

enter image description here

In the first example I have four lines and second has three

```
Anchorage Oncology Centre
3801 University Lake Drive
Suite 300-B2
Anchorage, AK 99508 US
```

I would like the above as split into 5 cells. One cell each for address, City, State, Zip code and country

```
Anchorage Oncology Centre
3801 University Lake Drive
Suite 300-B2


Anchorage

AK 

99508 

US
```

in second example below

```
Providence Alaska Medical Center
3200 Providence Drive
Anchorage, AK 99508 US
```

I would like

```
Providence Alaska Medical Center
3200 Providence Drive

Anchorage

AK 

99508 

US
```

Could this be done using a formula?

What I have done so far is that the full address is in cell `A1` and I want them in `B1`, `C1`, `D1`, `E1`, and `F1`. What i have done is for the country I use `=RIGHT(A2,2)`, zip code, i use `=MID(A2, LEN(A2)-7, 5)`, state `=MID(A2, LEN(A2)-10, 2)`. Now I am trying to extract the city. The city is before the comma and after the line break `(Char(10))` and Address is first 2 or 3 lines. I don't know how to do that.

There is a line break between each line.

Thank you

Comment: The full address is in cell A1 and I want them in B1, C1, D1, E1, and F1. What i have done is for the country I use =RIGHT(A2,2), zip code, i use =MID(A2, LEN(A2)-7, 5), state =MID(A2, LEN(A2)-10, 2). Now I am trying to extract the city. The city is before the comma and after the line break (Char(10)) and Address is first 2 or 3 lines. I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `SUBSTITUTE()` you can substitute the n'th occurrence of a character with a new character, then use `FIND()` to return that character. For example, if you `SUBSTITUTE` your `CHAR(10)`, the third occurrence, you can find that character again that would be the end of the address.

So if your FULL address is in A1, then you could extract the address with `LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"~",3)))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am passing the line break dynamically 2 or 3 from a different cell and extract address and city. I "wrap text" address and it is perfect.

Comment: Glad I could help! Hit that check-mark to say that my answer helped, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be

```
=IF(ROW(A1)<SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$7<>"")*1),A1,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A$1:A$7,SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$7<>"")*1)),",",)," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(X1)-SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$7<>"")*1)+1)*999-998,999)))
```

The split part [is from here](http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=326):

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A$2," ",REPT(" ",999)),ROW(X1)*999-998,999))
```

I have added some calculations to find the last row and eliminate commas:

```
SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A$1:A$7,SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$7<>"")*1)),",",)
```

If all the adresses are located in the first row, then u can insert the formula below the adress in column one and copy it down and to the right. Currently the address can have 7 lines, so u have to copy it at least to line 8.

[image]

Comment: @Overflostacker I want them in the same row. The full address is in cell A1 and i want them in B1, C1, D1, E1, and F1. What i have done is for the country I use =RIGHT(A2,2), zip code, i use =MID(A2, LEN(A2)-7, 5), state =MID(A2, LEN(A2)-10, 2). Now i am trying to extract city. City is before the comma and after the line break (Char(10)) and Address is first 2 or 3 lines. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: @user176047 you say in this comment that you want the result in the same row, but the image of your result shows a column layout - it is incumbent on you to make what you want clear.