# How to get string in between two characters in excel/spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this string

```
Weiss,Emery/Ap #519-8997 Quam. Street/Hawaiian Gardens,IN - 79589|10/13/2010
```

how do I get the Hawaiian Gardens only?

I already tried Using some

```
=mid(left(A1,find("/",A1)-1),find(",",A1)+1,len(A1))
```

it gives me emery instead

Comment: This might be very hard to handle using pure Excel.  If you have long term needs similar to this, it might be worthwhile to spend some time learning about VBA for Excel.  From VBA code, you would have a number of options for handling this problem.

Comment: are there always two `/` before the search term?

Comment: Yes, there is always / and , between the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are always **two** slashes before the string you want to extract, based on[Tyler M's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56366310/10068520) answer you can use this

```
=MID(E1,
     FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(E1,"/","~",2))+1,
     FIND(",",RIGHT(E1,LEN(E1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(E1,"/","~",2))))-1
     )
```

This substitutes the second occurence of `/` with a character which normally would not occur in the address, thus making it findable.

Answer (score 2):

Was your intention to also include Google Spreadsheets (looking at your title)? If so,you can use the `REGEXEXTRACT()` function. For example in `B1`

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\/([\w\s]*)\,")
```

[image]

In Excel you could build a UDF using this regex rule like so (as an example):

```
Function REGEXEXTRACT(S As String, PTRN As String) As String

'We will get the last possible match in your string...
Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regex
    .Pattern = PTRN
    .Global = True
End With

Set matches = regex.Execute(S)
For Each Match In matches
    If Match.SubMatches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each subMatch In Match.SubMatches
            REGEXEXTRACT = subMatch
        Next subMatch
    End If
Next Match

End Function
```

Call the function in `B1` like so:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\/([\w\s]*)\,")
```

[image]